# Need help in summing up difference by id in array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array I want to sum up by "service_request_id" and get array like below. Can somebody help me to achieve the same?

I have tried reduced and map but how to group and sum values?

```
    let desiredResult = [
      {
        product_name: 'Gitlab',
        service_request_id: 1,
        request_id: 378,
        value: 10,
        fulfillment_started_at: '2022/8/9'
      },
      {
        product_name: 'Opsera',
        service_request_id: 1,
        request_id: 377,
        value: 20,
        fulfillment_started_at: '2022/8/9'
      },
         {
        product_name: 'Opsera',
        service_request_id: 2,
        request_id: 379,
        value: 20,
        fulfillment_started_at: '2022/8/9'
      }
    ]
```

I have tried reduced and map but how to group and sum values?

```
[
      {
        "service_request_id": 1,
        "value": 30,
        "fulfillment_started_at": "2022/8/9",
        "breakup": [
          {
            "request_id": 377,
            "category": "Opsera",
            "value": 20,
          },
          {
            "request_id": 378,
            "category": "Gitlab",
            "value": 10,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "service_request_id": 2,
        "value": 26,
        "fulfillment_started_at": "2022/8/10",
        "breakup": [
          {
            "request_id": 379,
            "category": "Opsera",
            "value": 20,
          }]
]
```

This is what I tried so far:

```js
let desiredResult = [
  {
    product_name: 'Gitlab',
    service_request_id: 1,
    request_id: 378,
    value: 10,
    fulfillment_started_at: '2022/8/9'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'Opsera',
    service_request_id: 1,
    request_id: 377,
    value: 20,
    fulfillment_started_at: '2022/8/9'
  },
     {
    product_name: 'Opsera',
    service_request_id: 2,
    request_id: 379,
    value: 20,
    fulfillment_started_at: '2022/8/9'
  }
]

let final=[];
var sums = {};
for (var i = 0; i < desiredResult.length; i++) {
  var obj = desiredResult[i];
  sums[obj.service_request_id] = sums[obj.service_request_id] === undefined ? 0 : sums[obj.service_request_id];
  sums[obj.service_request_id] += parseInt(obj.difference);
    newobj={}
    newobj['service_request_id']={"total":sums[obj.service_request_id]}
    newobj['service_request_id'] = obj.service_request_id
  //  if(!Array.isArray(newobj['breakup'])) newobj['breakup']=[]
    
    final.push(newobj)
}

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Can you show the code with what you have tried so far?

Comment: i have tried like this let final=[];
var sums = {};
for (var i = 0; i < desiredResult.length; i++) {
  var obj = desiredResult[i];
  sums[obj.service_request_id] = sums[obj.service_request_id] === undefined ? 0 : sums[obj.service_request_id];
  sums[obj.service_request_id] += parseInt(obj.difference);
    newobj={}
    newobj['service_request_id']={"total":sums[obj.service_request_id]}
  //  if(!Array.isArray(newobj['breakup'])) newobj['breakup']=[]
    final.push(newobj)
}

Comment: Update your question. Code is horrible to read in comments and people likely will not read all the comments.

Comment: @PeterKrebs updated question with code

Comment: I have made your code a runnable snippet (the `<>` button). In this line: `newobj['service_request_id'] = obj.service_request_id` you overwrite the whole object you created the line before. This seems unintentional.

Answer (score 0):

With reduce, you can build the final object by adding orders if they don't exist, and products if the order exists.

```js
let desiredResult = [
    {
        product_name: "Gitlab",
        service_request_id: 1,
        request_id: 378,
        value: 10,
        fulfillment_started_at: "2022/8/9",
    },
    {
        product_name: "Opsera",
        service_request_id: 1,
        request_id: 377,
        value: 20,
        fulfillment_started_at: "2022/8/9",
    },
    {
        product_name: "Opsera",
        service_request_id: 2,
        request_id: 379,
        value: 20,
        fulfillment_started_at: "2022/8/9",
    },
];


const result = desiredResult.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const order = acc.findIndex(
        ({ service_request_id }) => service_request_id === curr.service_request_id
    );
    if (order === -1) {
        acc.push({
            service_request_id: curr.service_request_id,
            value: curr.value,
            fulfillment_started_at: curr.fulfillment_started_at,
            breakup: [
                {
                    request_id: curr.request_id,
                    category: curr.product_name,
                    value: curr.value,
                },
            ],
        });
    } else {
        acc[order].value += curr.value;
        acc[order].breakup.push({
            request_id: curr.request_id,
            category: curr.product_name,
            value: curr.value,
        });
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```